# php transforming a specific string into array values

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

i get this response from the server:

```
OK: 0; Sent queued message ID: e3674786a1c5f7a1 SMSGlobalMsgID:6162865783958235 OK: 0; Sent queued message ID: 9589936487b8d0a1 SMSGlobalMsgID:6141138716371692
```

and so on...

This is just one long string with NO carriage return i copied it exactly as received.
please note, initial OK can be a different word as well as 0 (at the beginning of the string) can be upto 3 digits number.

this is the pattern that repeats itself:

```
OK: 0; Sent queued message ID: e3674786a1c5f7a1 SMSGlobalMsgID:6162865783958235
```

i would like to transform it into an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
           [1] => OK
           [2] => 0
           [3] => e3674786a1c5f7a1
           [4] => 6162865783958235

    [1] => Array
           [1] => OK
           [2] => 0
           [3] => 9589936487b8d0a1
           [4] => 6141138716371692 
)
```

How would you go about it? I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you have that data as a string as input :

```
$str = <<<STR
OK: 0; Sent queued message ID: e3674786a1c5f7a1 SMSGlobalMsgID:6162865783958235
OK: 0; Sent queued message ID: 9589936487b8d0a1 SMSGlobalMsgID:6141138716371692
STR;
```

A solution would be to [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) that string into separate lines :

```
$lines = explode("\n", $str);
```

---

*Edit after the comment and the edit of the OP*

Considering the data you receive is on only one line, you'll have to find another way to split it *(I think it's easier splitting the data and working on "lines" that working on a big chunk of data at once)*.

Considering the data you're receiving looks like this :

```
$str = <<<STR
OK: 0; Sent queued message ID: e3674786a1c5f7a1 SMSGlobalMsgID:6162865783958235 OK: 0; Sent queued message ID: 9589936487b8d0a1 SMSGlobalMsgID:6141138716371692
STR;
```

I suppose you could split it in "lines", with [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split), using a regex such as this one :

```
$lines = preg_split('/SMSGlobalMsgID: (\d+) /', $str);
```

If you try to output the content of `$lines`, it seems quite OK -- and you should now be able to iterate over thoses lines.

---

Then, you start by initializing the `$output` array as an empty one :

```
$output = array();
```

And you now have to loop over the lines of the initial input, using some regex magic on each line :

See the documentation of [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) and [`Regular Expressions (Perl-Compatible)`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) for more informations

```
foreach ($lines as $line) {
  if (preg_match('/^(\w+): (\d+); Sent queued message ID: ([a-z0-9]+) SMSGlobalMsgID:(\d+)$/', trim($line), $m)) {
    $output[] = array_slice($m, 1);
  }
}
```

*Note the portions I captured, using `()`*

And, in the end, you get the `$output` array :

```
var_dump($output);
```

That looks like this :

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string 'OK' (length=2)
      1 => string '0' (length=1)
      2 => string 'e3674786a1c5f7a1' (length=16)
      3 => string '6162865783958235' (length=16)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string 'OK' (length=2)
      1 => string '0' (length=1)
      2 => string '9589936487b8d0a1' (length=16)
      3 => string '6141138716371692' (length=16)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but as I stated theres no carriege return so \n will not work. + initial OK can be a different value as well as 0 can be upto 3 digits number. sorry i didnt state it, Ill update the post

Comment: Oh :-( I just copy-pasted the string from your question, and it was on two lines, before your edit ^^ ;; I'll try a couple of ideas, and edit my answer if I find something useful :-)   *(edit of my comment : I've just edited my answer to provide some additionnal info -- should work with the non-multiline input, now)*

Comment: *"initial OK can be a different value as well as 0 can be upto 3 digits number"* >> my code should work for that, as I matched `\d+`, which means *"at least one number"*.

Comment: tried it and the vardump -> array(0) { } 
ill have a look into it tomorrow... and tick off your solution if i get it to work using it.

Comment: first it failed on $lines = preg_split('/SMSGlobalMsgID: (\d+) /', $str); 
there is no space after the colon. and then in the results it didnt show SMSGlobalID as it was removed by preg_split and then i output only one array, but i guess it was because the line didnt match the preg_match pattern very well (as the SMSGlobalID was missing)